# getting null value in the controller while submitting the form

Tags: spring-mvc

Here i am submitting the form using submit action. In Controller the model object is showing null value. Suppose i am using request.getParameter("mcodeName") - then i am getting value.  Whey value is null when i using getMcode() method. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/masterCode.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addMasterCode(HttpServletRequest req, 
            HttpServletResponse res, @ModelAttribute("masterCodeBean") MasterCodeBean mCodeBeanObj) { 
        log.info("");
        String mCodeName    = mCodeBeanObj.getMaster_code_name(); //getting null
        String mCodeStatus  = mCodeBeanObj.isActive(); //getting null
        System.out.println("Req code des " + req.getParameter("mCodeName"));
        System.out.println("Req active : " + req.getParameter("active"));
        ModelAndView model = null;
        try {
            model = new ModelAndView("masterCode");
            codeDelegate.addMasterCodeDetails(mCodeBeanObj);
            model.addObject("masterCodeBean", mCodeBeanObj);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(EXCEP_ERR);
        }
        return model;
    }
```

my form bind model attribute like

Comment: <pre>
<form:form id="mCodeForm" method="post" action="masterCode.do" modelAttribute="masterCodeBean">
 Enter Product Name : 
    <form:input id="mCodeName" name="mCodeName" path="" /> <br></div>
    Select Status : <form:select id="active" name="active" path="">
       <form:option value="0" label="Active" />
       <form:option value="1" label="De-Active" />
      </form:select>
  <span> <input type="submit" value="Save"  id="save_mstCdeMgr"/> </span> 
</form:form>
</pre>

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputations to comment on. So I am writing the answer here.

```
<form:form id="mCodeForm" method="post" action="masterCode.do" modelAttribute="masterCodeBean"> 
Enter Product Name : <form:input id="mCodeName" path="mCodeName" /> <br>
Select Status : <form:select id="active" path="isActive"> 
<form:option value="0" label="Active" /> 
<form:option value="1" label="De-Active" /> 
</form:select> 
<span> <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_mstCdeMgr"/> </span> </form:form>
```

1. The setters and getters should follow some code conventions.
   Suppose if you have `mCodeName` as class variable then `getMCodeName()` and `setMCodeName(String mCodeName)`.
2. As you used form tag, the path is nothing but the `modelAttribute` field name. No need of writing id and name attributes as it generates them at run-time. The id is needed for some client-side validation or javascript related purposes.

   `<form:input id="mCodeName" path="mCodeName" />` is converted into the html code at run-time as `<input  type="text" id="mCodeName" name="mCodeName" />`

Try this and let me know.